# Why I can't get a post request in the controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-routing

I want to get the body of a post in a controller.

Here is my code:

```
[HttpPost]
public string GetMsg([FromBody]GetMsgModel GSM)
{
    return "";
}
```

And posted class

```
public class GetMsgModel { 
    public string ToUserName { get; set; }
    public string FromUserName { get; set; }
    public string CreateTime { get; set; }
    public string MsgType { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public string MsgId { get; set; }
}
```

I added a breakpoint to the `GetMsg` and send a post via postman with this XML body:

```xml
<xml>
  <ToUserName>123</ToUserName>
  <FromUserName>456</FromUserName>
  <CreateTime>1348831860</CreateTime>
  <MsgType>789</MsgType>
  <Content>000</Content>
  <MsgId>1234567890123456</MsgId>
</xml>
```

[image]

Well, the breakpoint does not run at all.

What's wrong with this? There is another `HttpGet` method in the same controller and it works well. It seems it is not the problem of the controller yet.

Comment: Are you sure you configured your API server to be able to handle XML requests? Also, do you specify correct header in HTTP request for XML file?

Comment: @IskanderRaimbayev I am a beginner and I am not sure about that. In my opinion, the XML requests are just string so I wrote the code as above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using Net Core
Add to Statup.cs

```cs
services.AddXmlSerializerFormatters();
```

And the XML should be

```xml
<GetMsgModel>
  <ToUserName>123</ToUserName>
  <FromUserName>456</FromUserName>
  <CreateTime>1348831860</CreateTime>
  <MsgType>789</MsgType>
  <Content>000</Content>
  <MsgId>1234567890123456</MsgId>
</GetMsgModel>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I am using .net core 3.0 now, via the Microsoft official page:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.mvcxmlmvcbuilderextensions.addxmlserializerformatters?view=aspnetcore-2.2&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-3.0 the AddXmlSerializerFormatters no longer exists in .net core 3.0 yet.

Comment: Well, I found it on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-3.0  . In .net core 3.0 , it has modified to services.AddControllers()
        .AddXmlSerializerFormatters();